# Pegar valor da variavel no retorno da funcao

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.fetchData = function (param) {
   var url = param;
   var thumb;
   var imgid = get_numbers(url);
   var hash = ("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + imgid + ".json");
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: hash
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     thumb = response.data[0].thumbnail_medium;
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("Request fail");
   });
   return thumb;
};


function get_numbers(input) {
   return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
}

var imgthumb = $scope.fetchData("http://player.vimeo.com/video/219839519");
alert(imgthumb);
```

Exemplo: quando eu fizer console.log da variável thumb dentro da função then, consigo ver o valor da variável, mas quando for fazer o retorno da função principal o valor da variável e indefinido.

Comment: Colega, descreva melhor seu problema e formate seu código.

Comment: Pegar o que? Aonde?

Answer (score 1):

fica assim

```
 $scope.fetchData = function (param) {
                             var defer = $q.defer();
                            var url = param;
                            var thumb;
                            var imgid = get_numbers(url);
                            var hash = ("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + imgid + ".json");
                            $http({
                                method: 'GET',
                                url: hash

                            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                                thumb = response.data[0].thumbnail_medium;
                                return  defer.resolve(thumb);

                            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                                return deferred.reject('fail');
                            });

                            return defer.promise;
                        };


                        function get_numbers(input) {
                            return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
                        }

                        var imgthumb = $scope.fetchData("http://player.vimeo.com/video/219839519");

                        console.log(imgthumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi, você está tendo dificuldade para receber o retorno na variável `imgthumb`, pois o http.get é executado de modo assíncrono.
Para isso, faça:

```
$scope.fetchData = function (param) {
   var url = param;
   var thumb;
   var imgid = get_numbers(url);
   var hash = ("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + imgid + ".json");
   return $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: hash
   });
};


function get_numbers(input) {
   return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
}

$scope.fetchData("http://player.vimeo.com/video/219839519").then(function successCallback(response) {
      alert(response.data[0].thumbnail_medium);
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("Request fail");
   });
```

Comment: ok, ate ai esta tudo certo, mas na hora de fazer o retorno da função o valor da variável vem como undefined.

Comment: Qual variável está undefined??

Comment: isso ai,  thumb = response.data[0].thumbnail_medium; Quando for fazer um return na função principal fica undefined

Comment: Não adianta querer retornar de uma função assíncrona, @HumbertoLopes.

Comment: ok, resolvido, estava faltando alguma coisa do angularjs, o   var defer = $q.defer();